# Do integrity levels only apply to executable files?

Tags: windows, windows-8, uac

Does the "Integrity level" property of an NTFS file only have an effect for files which are executable and executed? Or can changing the integrity level (e.g. via `icacls`) on a "data" file have an effect of its own as well, e.g. do the integrity levels need to "match" (by some check) for A.exe to open B.txt without additional UAC prompts?

(The back story: I'd like to give a medium-level app access to a file on disk, which it only seems to be able to access if I launch that app as an Administrator. The app does not know how to open a UAC prompt on its own to gain access to the file.)

[image]

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625962.aspx